# How to run Docker and node.js with remote configurations

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, docker, config

I'd like to provide an easy and simple Docker container for an open source application that takes an URL of a configuration file as an argument and uses this file.

The Dockerfile is pretty straight forward:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage
# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs git
ADD     . /src
RUN     cd /src; npm install; npm update
ENV NODE_ENV production
CMD     ["/usr/bin/node", "/src/gitevents.js"]
```

I found no way of adding the file when the container runs (with ADD or ENTRYPOINT), so I'm trying to work it out in node.js:

```
docker run -e "CONFIG_URL=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/PatrickHeneise/c97ba221495df0cd9a3b/raw/fda1b8cd53874735349c6310a6643e6fc589a404/gitevents_config.js" gitevents
```

this sets `CONFIG_URL` as a environment variable that I can use in node. However, I need to download a file then, which is async, which kind of doesn't work in the current setup.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  var exists = fs.accessSync(path.join(__dirname, 'common', 'production.js'), fs.R_OK);
  if (exists) {
    config = require('./production');
  } else {
    // https download, but then `config` is undefined when running the app the first time.
  }
}
```

There's no synchronous download in node.js, any recommendations how I could solve this?

I'd love to have Docker do the job with `ADD` or `CMD` doing a curl download, but I'm not sure how that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing would be to consider that your "config file" is not a file but just text and pass the content to the container at runtime.

CONFIG="$(curl -sL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/PatrickHeneise/c97ba221495df0cd9a3b/raw/fda1b8cd53874735349c6310a6643e6fc589a404/gitevents_config.js)"

docker run -e "CONFIG_URL=${CONFIG}" gitevents

Answer (score 1):

How about a combination of `ENTRYPOINT` and environment variable? You'd have `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile set to a shell script that would download the configuration file specified in the environment variable and then start the application.
Since the entry point script would receive whatever is in `CMD` as it's arguments, the application start step could be accomplished by something like

```
# Execute CMD.
eval "$@"
```

Comment: That sounds interesting. I'll try that.

Comment: I wrote a file `init.sh` with the curl command and then running node, but that feels kind of dirty. Running the script via CMD from the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to re-write my config script to work asynchronous, still not the best solution in my eyes.

```
var config = {};
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

config.load = function(fn) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    fs.access(path.join(__dirname, 'production.js'), fs.R_OK, function(error, exists) {
      if (exists) {
        config = require('./production');
      } else {
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'production.js'));
        var url = process.env.CONFIG_URL;

        if (!url) {
          process.exit(-1);
        } else {
          https.get(url, function(response) {
            response.pipe(file);
            file.on('finish', function() {
              file.close(function() {
                return fn(require('./production'));
              });
            });
          });
        }
      }
    });
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    return fn(require('./test'));
  } else {
    return fn(require('./development'));
  }
};

module.exports = exports = config;
```